# Class has no constructor, but it has and with right parameters

Tags: c++, constructor

```
class Iterator;

class SortedList {

    friend class Iterator;

private:
    Node* root;

    Node* minim(Node* node) const {
        while (node->getLeft() != nullptr)
            node = node->getLeft();
        return node;
};

public:
    SortedList() {
        root = nullptr;
    };

    Iterator iterator() {
        Node* min = minim(root);
        return Iterator(*this, min); // Here says that Iterator has no constructors
    };
};  


class Iterator {
private:
    const SortedList& list;
    Node* current;

public:
    Iterator(const SortedList& list, Node* current) : list{ list }, current{ current } {};

};
```

It says int the iterator method of SortedList that the Iterator class doesn't have constructors also doesn't say about matching or not and if i modify some parameters to be incorrect it does specify that there aren't any with those parameters.

Another thing, if i comment the iterator method out and instantiate an iterator in main by writing Iterator it { my parameters} it works just fine.

Comment: Do **not** put `;` after the final `}` of your functions!

Comment: Before you define `Iterator` it is an incomplete type, and you cannot do much with an incomplete type.

Comment: It sounds more like you want to have Iterator depend on a forward-declared `SortedList`, and `SortedList` depend on a complete`Iterator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Iterator` is an incomplete type when you use:

```
Iterator iterator() {
    Node* min = minim(root);
    return Iterator(*this, min); // Here says that Iterator has no constructors
};
```

Move the definition of the function after definition of `Iterator`.

```
class Iterator;

class SortedList {

    friend class Iterator;

private:
    Node* root;

    Node* minim(Node* node) const {
        while (node->getLeft() != nullptr)
            node = node->getLeft();
        return node;
};

public:
    SortedList() {
        root = nullptr;
    };

    // Just the declaration
    Iterator iterator();
};  


class Iterator {
private:
    const SortedList& list;
    Node* current;

public:
    Iterator(const SortedList& list, Node* current) : list{ list }, current{ current } {};

};

// Now the definition    
Iterator SortedList::iterator() {
   Node* min = minim(root);
   return Iterator(*this, min);
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works now.

An interesting note: i have something similar, but templated and there worked without this "trick" is there any difference i should know?

Comment: @Lorand: Templates are "compile when used". At the point where the template is used, both definitions are probably already available.